# How can I prevent DIVs from overlapping a right floated image?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a document with two images and some text. The first image is floated left, the second one floated right.

The problem is that text from DIVs overlaps the second image. The text "*First DIV after second image*" should be placed below the first image and to the left of the second image (since it's after the second `IMG` tag). What am I missing?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yLUnC/4/

[image: example screenshot]

Html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>DIV before first image</div>
    <img class="floatLeft" src="http://placehold.it/200x100&text=First+image">
    <div>DIV after first, before second</div>
    <img class="floatRight" src="http://placehold.it/200x100&text=Second+image">
    <div>First DIV after second image</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text overlapping second image, not good</div>
    <div>last DIV</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to give all the Child elements `display:inline` and give other special elements `display: block`. and also most important thing is to give `overflow: auto` to the parent element so that it counts the height of the floated child elements (such as the second image).

Here is the [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/yLUnC/5/)

**Update**:

As you have not assigned any classes to those elements, I am adding inline styling to those special elements.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yLUnC/7/)** (*Change as you need*)

Comment: Looks good at first glance, but now the divs are all on one line instead of looking like paragraphs (my intention).

Comment: @Mark As I mentioned, give the special elements. `display: block`.

Comment: I looking for a more general solution, I'm afraid. The actual divs can change based on user input (it's a text editor).