# Why div above another div when window minimize

Tags: html, css

Hey guys I've a problem with position of div.
I've made two div using `float: left`.
But when I minimize the window, second div go above the first div and it is shit!

How can I do?

I want that the div don't overlap...

Here is the link:

https://jsfiddle.net/p25zrpke/1/

```
<style>
body{margin:0;paffing:0;border:1px solid black;}
#first{width:10%;float:left; border:1px solid black;}
#second{width:50%;float:left;border:1px solid black;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="first">
<p>Descrizione</p>
<p>Galleria</p>
<p>Locali consigliati</p>
<p>Camere</p>
<p>Albergo</p>
</div>
<div id="second">
Lorem Ipsum è un testo segnaposto utilizzato nel settore della tipografia e della stampa. Lorem Ipsum è considerato il testo segnaposto standard sin dal sedicesimo secolo, quando un anonimo tipografo prese una cassetta di caratteri e li assemblò per preparare un testo campione. È sopravvissuto non solo a più di cinque secoli, ma anche al passaggio alla videoimpaginazione, pervenendoci sostanzialmente inalterato. Fu reso popolare, negli anni ’60, con la diffusione dei fogli di caratteri trasferibili “Letraset”, che contenevano passaggi del Lorem Ipsum, e più recentemente da software di impaginazione come Aldus PageMaker, che includeva versioni del Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
```

[I've google chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8Izs.png)

Thanks, and sorry for my bad english...

Comment: I envision Bootstrap in your future.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem, the divs remain next to each other

Comment: @Aziz Same. Cannot replicate.

Comment: What browser is that happening in?  Do you have screen shots?

Comment: @Jeremy  I've google chrome http://i.stack.imgur.com/b8Izs.png

Comment: So your "paffing: 0"?

Comment: Might be a duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209837/how-can-i-prevent-divs-from-overlapping-a-right-floated-image

What is paffing btw?

Comment: Remove `width: 10%`?

Comment: Fantasy man... paffing is padding

Comment: @Cenzy, the screenshot you showed me is correct.  The words are overlapping into the next DIV.  Words do not break by default.  The comment below answers your question (word-wrap:break-word;).  Your wording was confusing.  Overlapping was the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `word-wrap: break-word;` to your CSS. Job done :)

Comment: It works! Thanks man!

Comment: @Cenzy Accept it as answer if it solve your issue by clicking on right symbol